# How would I go about dual booting KALI with UBUNTU

Tags: boot, dual-boot, usb, uefi, grub-efi

I have a USB drive with 8GB plugged into my port for about 3 hours trying to figure out how I go about dual booting Kali onto my Ubuntu. Yes, that is crazy.

- using ubuntu 14.04 LTS as current OS
- Running on a HP Notebook Laptop

*In addition, I've searched for duplicate answers and none applied.*

This popped up for my USB drive:

[image]

What are the proper steps to take

Please and thank you very, very much.

Comment: Do you have a UEFI system?

Comment: Is that Windows based? @mchid

Comment: @mchid 'Let Me Google That For You' links are considered in bad taste here on this site - this has been a long standing feeling of "don't post these" to LMGTFY links and pure 'RTFM'-like links and comments and answers.  Please do not post such links.

Comment: Typically, if your computer was originally Windows7 you typically should have a standard BIOS system. If your computer came with Windows8 or 10 it should have UEFI.

Comment: @ThomasW. Really? I figured I was "*teaching a man to fish*".

Comment: @mchid [Refer to Meta](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/13507/lmgtfy-is-it-allowed/13508#13508).  We have a big fat "NO" on those types of links - we consider it degrading towards users to post such links.  I.E., it's considered rude, so you shouldn't do it.

Comment: @mchid Yes, it was Windows 8! Thank you!

Comment: This topic is discussed here: https://forums.kali.org/showthread.php?271-How-to-EFI-install-Kali-Linux but the link for the needed file is dead on that page and you can download the needed file from here instead http://archives.fedoraproject.org/pub/archive/fedora/linux/releases/18/Fedora/x86_64/os/EFI/BOOT/ to get it working.  Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

While this is most likely not what you are looking to do, I suggest using Kali as a bootable flashdrive. Using Unetbootin, and a Kali image you can have easy access to Kali on most devices. Since Kali wasn't originally meant to leave files behind, this may provide a temporary solution